# Deterring Neighborhood Cat (Humanely)

Tags: cats, training, defecation

A neighborhood cat is entering our yard and going to the bathroom, killing unsuspecting birds, chipmunks, and other wildlife. The cat's owners will not keep her inside in the short term--they've made this very clear. They are also unlikely to restrain her to an enclosed area.

I'm trying to live with this as best I can. The first thing I'm doing is to deploy an outside litter box for the cat on the edge of my property. Can anyone else suggest some cat deterrent steps they've taken in the past that have actually worked?

This cat is young, swift, and an excellent hunter. She already wears a bell and also scales large fences and trees without a problem. Any other suggestions? I haven't tried the oils and spikes, but I'm very skeptical of their effectiveness. I also don't want to hurt her.

Answer (score 1):

There are motion-detecting lawn sprinklers. That might at least help put part of the yard off limits. Unless this is one of the cats that likes playing with water.

That won't reduce the kill rate -- the cat will just go elsewhere -- but it will help you ignore it.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, thank you.